# Powershell - Passing credentials to script block without using Jobs or Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell-2.0, credentials

We have a Windows user created at Dev environment and we need to execute all operation under security context of that user.

Till now we found that there are only two ways to pass credentials to a scriptblock
1. Using Start-Job
2. Invoke-Command

But we are facing performance issues with Jobs and for Invoke-Command we need to enable WinRm at remote server, but we don't have access to start it.

Is there any other solution to pass credentials to script block without using above mentioned options or any work-around for above mentioned options?

Answer (score 0):

you can write a self calling script .

```
if  (-not $args) { 
   $quiet=Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer * –Force -verbose
   $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Authentication Credssp -credential "<Your Username>" 
   $myDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
   $myfile=Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
   cd $myDir #for ise working dir
invoke-command -Session $session -filepath $myfile -ArgumentList $session
exit
 }

#here take your code in
```

regards Ingo